# Are there OpenCL bindings that aren't written in C/C++ style?

Tags: c++, binding, opencl

The current OpenCL C++ bindings in `CL/cl.hpp` are a *very* thin wrapper over the C OpenCL API. I understand reasons why it was done this way, although I actually really don't.

Are there any existing alternative wrappers which rely on exceptions as error handling, allowing one to just write code like this:

```
auto platform_list = cl::Platform::get();
```

because, well, RVO and readability and such, instead of the current

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> platform_list;
auto error = cl::Platform::get(&platformList);
if(error != CL_SUCCESS)
```

Or if one opts in on exception handling (by defining `__CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS`):

```
std::vector<cl::Platform> platform_list;
cl::Platform::get(&platformList);
```

Note the actual error handling code is not shown, although in the non-exceptions case this can get quite messy.

I'm sure such bindings would not be terribly hard to write, but edge cases remain edge cases and I'd prefer a solid pre-written wrapper. Call me spoiled, but if C++ bindings do not offer a real C++ interface, I don't really see the point of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Boost.Compute](https://github.com/kylelutz/compute) library. It is header-only and provides a high-level C++ API for GPGPU/parallel-computing based on OpenCL.

Getting the list of platforms looks like this:

```
for(auto platform : boost::compute::system::platforms()){
    std::cout << platform.vendor() << std::endl;
}
```

And it uses exceptions for error handling (which vastly reduces the amount of explicit checking required and gives much nicer error messages on failure):

```
try {
    // attempt to compile to program
    program.build();
}
catch(boost::compute::opencl_error &e){
    // program failed to compile, print out the build log
    std::cout << program.build_log() << std::endl;
}
```

On top of all that it also offers a STL-like interface with containers like [`vector<T>`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/vector.html) and [`array<T, N>`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/array.html) as well as algorithms like [`sort()`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/sort.html) and [`transform()`](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/boost/compute/transform.html) (along with other features like random number generation and lambda expression support).

For example, to sort a vector of `float`s on the device you just:

```
// vector of floats on the device
boost::compute::vector<float> vec = ...;

// sort the vector
boost::compute::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), queue);

// copy the sorted vector back to the host
boost::compute::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), host_vec.begin(), queue);
```

There are more tutorials and examples in the [documentation](http://kylelutz.github.io/compute/).

Answer (score 2):

The C++ wrappers are designed to be just a thin layer on top of OpenCL so they can be included just as a header file. There are some C++/OpenCL libraries that offer various kinds of support for C++, such as [AMD Bolt](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/opencl-libraries/bolt-c-template-library/).

There is a proposal for a layer/library for C++, SYCL. It is slightly more complex than a wrapper, as it requires a device compiler to produce OpenCL kernels, but provides (IMHO) nice abstractions and exception handling.
The provisional specification [is already available](http://www.khronos.org/opencl/sycl) , and there is already a (work in progress) [open source implementation](https://github.com/amd/triSYCL).